# How to get array of pixels from image

Tags: machine-learning, python, convolution

I read article about [learning to segment](https://research.facebook.com/blog/learning-to-segment/). I am wondering how to get the same array of numbers as in the [picture](https://scontent-arn2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/t39.2365-6/14050172_569626893245377_1599950311_n.jpg). Do I understand correctly that it is RGB? If possible, write an example in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Python provides API to load an image (Image lib) as well as for array management (Numpy lib)

Try for example

```
import Image 
import numpy as np 
im = Image.open("farm.jpg")
arr = np.array(im)
```

Comment: I already tried this, but the result is not like that in the article.